# Hey #AskFirebase, how should I design this schema?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, schema, nosql

I'm building an app in Firebase and could use some advice. Here are the key points:

- The app is for tracking time worked by employees.
- Users are divided into teams, with each team having a manager.
- As users clock in and out, the app tracks how long they work.

I'm stuck on a design problem. Here are the requirements:

- Managers can read & write the time cards for all users on their team, while users can only read & write their own.
- When users are viewing their own time cards, the UI needs to show most recent time cards sorted by timestamp.
- When managers are viewing the time cards of everyone on their team, the UI needs to show most recent time cards sorted by timestamp.

Solving for all 3 requirements simultaneously is proving to be a challenge. My first hunch was to structure the time cards like this:

```
{
  "timeCards": {
    "-teamId_1": {
      "-userId_1": {
        "-timeCard_1": {
          "startsAt: 1234567890123,
          "endsAt": 1234567899999,
          "duration": 2234567
        },
        "-timeCard_2": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This solves the first two requirements easily:

- Easy to write the permission rules such that managers have read/write for the entire team, but users can only read/write their own.
- Easy to query a specific user's hours sorted by timestamp w/ `db.ref('timeCards/${tid}/${uid}').orderByChild('startsAt')`

Unfortunately, to solve the 3rd requirement with this schema requires some heavy lifting on the client. There is no way (that I'm aware of) to query Firebase for all of a team's time cards sorted by timestamp. So, I'd have to pull down all time cards for the team, then merge & sort them on the client.

I'm thinking this calls for denormalization, maybe a structure like this:

```
{
  "timeCards": {
    "byTeam": {
      "-teamId_1": {
        "-timeCard_1": {
          "userId": "-userId_1",
          "startsAt: 1234567890123,
          "endsAt": 1234567899999,
          "duration": 2234567
        },
        "-timeCard_2": "..."
      }
    },
    "byUser": {
      "-userId_1": {
        "-timeCard_1": {
          "teamId": "-teamId_1",
          "startsAt: 1234567890123,
          "endsAt": 1234567899999,
          "duration": 2234567
        },
        "-timeCard_2": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this gets complicated on the server, requiring two Firebase functions, one watching `timeCards/byTeam` and one watching `timeCards/byUser`, that each mirror the records into the other collection.

I'm not sure how to avoid an infinite update loop in that situation, though. (Imagine updating `timeCards/byTeam/-teamId_1/-timeCard_1`, which fires the Firebase function and updates `timeCards/byUser/...`, which fires the Firebase function and updates `timeCards/byTeam/...`, etc.)

Am I missing an easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) good practice is to keep data as flat as possible. So it could look like this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "-userId_1": {
            "name": "John"
        },
        "-userId_2": {
            "name": "Ann"
        }
    },
    "teams": {
        "-teamId_1": {
            "name": "Gladiators"
        }
    },
    "timeCards": {
        "-timeCard_1": {
            "startsAt": 1234567890123,
            "endsAt": 1234567899999,
            "duration": 2234567,
            "userId": "-userId_1",
            "teamId": "-teamId_1"
        },
        "-timeCard_2": {
            "startsAt": 1234567890123,
            "endsAt": 1234567899999,
            "duration": 2234567,
            "userId": "-userId_2",
            "teamId": "-teamId_1"
        }
    },
    "usersInTeams": {
        "-teamId_1": {
            "-userId_1": true,
            "-userId_2": true
        }
    },
    "teamsInUsers": {
        "-userId_1": {
            "-teamId_1": true
        },
        "-userId_2": {
            "-teamId_1": true
        }
    },
    "timeCardsInUsers": {
        "-userId_1": {
            "-timeCard_1": true
        },
        "-userId_2": {
            "-timeCard_2": true
        }
    },
    "timeCardsInTeams": {
        "-teamId_1": {
            "-timeCard_1": true,
            "-timeCard_2": true
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could write a Cloud Function that triggers when you write to "timeCards" (node: `/timeCards/{pushId}`) and adds timeCard ID to "timeCardsInUsers" (node: `/timeCardsInUsers/{userId}`) and "timeCardsInTeams" (node: `/timeCardsInTeams/{teamId}`).

It should resolve the looping problem because you write to different nodes.